# Error trying to enable setting in profile

Tags: profile

I tried enabling a setting in a profile and I get the following error message:

```
Please fix the following:

Permission View All Data depends on permission(s): View Event Log Files
Permission Activate Contracts depends on permission(s): Edit Orders, Read Orders
Permission View All Data depends on permission(s): Read All Idea Themes, Read All Orders, Read All Scorecard Metrics, Read All Scorecards, Read All Signup Requests, Read All Social Posts, Read Orders, Read Scorecard Metrics, Read Scorecards, Read Signup Requests
```

Whenever I try fixing any of the required permissions I get a variation of the same error when saving the modification.

I'm afraid of turning off the **View All Data** permission and then fix the listed permissions in case I can't turn it back on but it sounds like I may not have a choice unless there is some other reason I'm not aware of that maybe causing this chain of permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, yes, this perplexed me for quite some time

You are no doubt using the Enhanced Profile Editor. Revert back (temporarily) to the "classic" Profile Editor and you can then set all of the permissions you need in a single transaction without having any of these cascading errors.

```
Customize | User Interface | Setup |Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface (uncheck)
```

Comment: Excellent!  That fixed my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Just chiming in to confirm that reverting back to the Classic Profile Editor (Go to Setup > User Management Settings, and disable the "Enhanced Profile User Interface") worked for me this afternoon after significant frustration (Today: 9/26/2018).